# Grep regular expression not working as expected

Tags: regex, grep

I have a simple `grep` command trying to get only the first column of a CSV file including the comma. It goes like this...

```
grep -Eo '^[^,]+,' some.csv
```

So in my head, that reads like "*get me only the matching part of the line where each line starts with at least one character that is not a comma, followed by a single comma*."

So on a file, `some.csv`, that looks like this:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
column1,column2,column3,column4
column1,column2,column3,column4
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
column1,
column1,
column1,
```

But I get this output:

```
column1,
column2,
column3,
column1,
column2,
column3,
column1,
column2,
column3,
```

Why is that? **What am I missing from my grep/regex?** Is my expected output incorrect?

If I remove the requirement of the trailing comma in the regex, the command works as I expect.

```
grep -Eo '^[^,]+' some.csv
```

Gives me:

```
column1
column1
column1
```

*NOTE:* I'm on macOS High Sierra with grep version: `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: It is not the only difference with GNU grep. If you see more of such discrepancies, it might be a better idea to [just install GNU grep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx) that [works as expected](https://ideone.com/ev5fKa).

Comment: I've seen some questions related to bugs in BSD grep... 1) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep 2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/grep-strange-behaviour-with-single-letter-words 3) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428340/how-to-make-bsd-grep-respect-start-of-line-anchor .. workaround could be to use sed/awk instead

Comment: BSD tools including awk are buggy and best avoided if possible. Get GNU tools. Having said that, even BSD sed should be able to handle `sed 's/^\([^,]*,\).*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSD `grep` is buggy in general. See the following related posts:

- [Why does this BSD grep result differ from GNU grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep)
- [grep strange behaviour with single letter words](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/grep-strange-behaviour-with-single-letter-words)
- [How to make BSD grep respect start-of-line anchor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428340/how-to-make-bsd-grep-respect-start-of-line-anchor)

That last link above mentions your case: when `-o` option is used, `grep` ignores the `^` anchor for some reason. This issue is also described in a [FreeBSD bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166842):

> I've noticed some more issues with the same version of grep. I don't
>   know whether they're related, but I'll append them here for now.
>
> `$ printf abc | grep -o '^[a-c]'`
>
> should just print 'a', but instead gives three hits, against each letter
>   of the incoming text.

As a workaround, it might be a better idea to just install [GNU grep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-osx) that [works as expected](https://ideone.com/ev5fKa).

Or, use `sed` with a BRE POSIX pattern:

```
sed -i '' 's/^\([^,]*,\).*/\1/' file
```

where the pattern matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `\([^,]*,\)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` backreference from the RHS):

  - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`
  - `,` - a `,` char
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Note that `-i` will change the file contents inplace. Use `-i.bak` to create a backup file if needed (then, you wouldn't need the next empty `''` though).

Comment: A mac doesn't come with BSD grep, it comes with GNU grep 2.5 - the last GPL2 licenced GNU grep. I can't reproduce the problem on FreeBSD. FreeBSD once did use GNU grep, hence the 2012 bug report.