# different outputs using same grep command with -e

Tags: bash, grep

I have a grep command:

```
grep -w -i -e "str1" -e "str2" -e "str3 ... -e "str30" file.txt
```

The issue is that I get different results based on where the strings are in the command, e.g if `str30` is position 2 it matches, if `str30` is in the last position nothing is matched. Other than that, the command is 100% the same, grepping the same file.

Is there something funky going on that grep will miss certain strings if they do not appear early on, or does it go through each line and check against each string? OR is there a certain limit of -e's that you can have per grep?

I am on OSX 10.13.4

Use case:

In case 1, the string to search is in the last position. In case 2, it is in the 2nd position. NOTE: In real case each grep has about 30 different strings to match against, they have been shortened here for brevity (** denotes the string for ease of reading, not the string to match)

```
grep -w -i -e "canDisplayBannerAds" -e "shouldPresentInterstitialAd" -e "rotatingHeaderView" -e "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" -e "bottomLayoutGuide" -e "modalViewController" -e "shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods" -e "**supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow**" encoder_classes.txt
```

NOTHING FOUND

```
grep -w -i -e "canDisplayBannerAds" -e "**supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow**" -e "rotatingHeaderView" -e "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" -e "bottomLayoutGuide" -e "modalViewController" -e "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" encoder_classes.txt

- (UIApplication *)arg1 supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)arg2;
- (UIApplication *)arg1 supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)arg2;
- (UIApplication *)arg1 supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)arg2;
```

EDIT:
test.txt contains `a...z` `aa...zz` `ccc`

case 1 has 'ccc' at the end and is not found

case 2 has 'ccc' at position 3 and is found

```
grep -w -i -e "a" -e "b" -e "c" -e "d" -e "f" -e "g" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "ccc" test.txt 

a
b
c
d
f
g

grep -w -i -e "a" -e "b" -e "ccc" -e "c" -e "d" -e "f" -e "g" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" -e "c" test.txt

a
b
c
d
f
g
ccc
```

EDIT2:

It seems that 'ccc' is not found unless it is in position 1,2, or 3, after position 3, it is no longer found in the file.

'ccc' in position 5 and is **not** found

```
grep -w -i -e "a" -e "b" -e "c" -e "d" -e "ccc" test.txt 
a
b
c
d
```

'ccc' in position 4 and is **not** found

```
grep -w -i -e "a" -e "b" -e "c" -e "ccc" test.txt 
a
b
c
```

'ccc' in position 3 and is found

```
grep -w -i -e "a" -e "b" -e "ccc" test.txt 
a
b
ccc
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with a sample input file so we can try to reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: have added further easier explanation, wasn't sure if you wanted me to upload a test file, or how I upload a file.

Comment: works fine on Fedora and Centos... please note that OSx does not use GNU grep, but POSIX grep, which works differently and it might be what not what you expect. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413494/does-grep-work-differently-on-osx

Comment: According to your example 'd' in the first example (EDIT2) should have not be found either (4 th place) but it does... 
What is your grep version? on Ubuntu 16.04 and grep (GNU grep) 2.25 it works for me too

Comment: I assume you have BSD grep..  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/grep-strange-behaviour-with-single-letter-words - might be same or related issue to yours .. there was another question about BSD grep bugs asked sday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240179/grep-regular-expression-not-working-as-expected

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD